# Find files that have been only once modified in last 24 hours

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm using this command to get all modified files in the last 24 hours on Ubuntu.

```sh
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n"
```

How can I modify this to detect that a file has been modified more than a single time? And if so, ignore it.

I need this to create a watermarking script which will find the latest files within 24 hours and save the list to a text file and with the help of this text file, I use `ffmpeg` to watermark the videos and move them to the original location.

If I do this, the find command considers the new updated video as a modified file and adds the watermark repeatedly.

My code is attached below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -mtime -1 -printf "%f\n" >> filename='/home/domain.com/public_html/admin_panel/public_html/uploads/mp4/temp/file.txt'
all_lines=`cat $filename` 
for item in $all_lines; do  
  cp $item /home/domain.com/public_html/admin_panel/public_html/uploads/mp4/temp 
  ffmpeg -i $item -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*30/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)"
-y /home/domain.com/public_html/admin_panel/public_html/uploads/mp4/temp/$item 
done
```

Comment: Only few filesystems have the capability to track how many times a file has been modified, but this is a very non-standard practice. `zfs` for example can keep snapshots of each modification, so you could use these snapshots to check if a file has been modified with a particular granularity. But the general answer to your question is: _No, this cannot be done! Imagine someone edits a file and saves it every millisecond. You would have a modification count of 1000 after one second._

Comment: Sir my main aim is to watermark videos in the main folder,For doing this i wrote a code to find the latest modified files and list them in a text file so that these files in the list are watermarked with ffmpeg and moved back to original directory,So is ther any other way to do this watermarking other than this process?

Comment: There is no way to do this unless you have a proper filesystem in place or all modifications have been logged in a log-file with a proper timestamp. If you have such log-file, you could parse it and extract the needed information.